# Disprove a limit using epsilon definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

> **Disprove:**  If $\{x_n\}$ is any sequence, and $\{s_n\}$ is a sequence converging to $0$, then $$\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} x_n s_n=0$$

I'm not sure how to go about solving this proof. I tried a couple of different things, but I just realized I've been solving proofs via rote and I don't really understand the solution to a proof.

Thus, attempting to disprove a problem exposed some gaps in my understanding as I don't know what I'm trying to disprove.

First, to prove a limit problem I suppose I'm trying to show that there is some $n$ (which I visualize as being the x coordinate) that is greater than some $N$ (which I visualize as being some point on the x coordinate).  $\epsilon$ just tells me how far past that point (y coordinate) I am; thus $n$ and $N$ must be less than $\epsilon$.

For this problem then I figured I just need to show that $x_n$ is unbounded, because and unbounded $x_n$ means the function doesn't converge to $0$.

Is disproving this as simple as taking the product of the limits and showing that it DNE?

Comment: You just need to find one counterexample.  Try considering possible $x_n$'s s.t. $\lim x_n = \infty$.

Comment: @Bye_World I think so because the function is decreasing or increasing without bounds?

Comment: Right.  The way to *cancel out* (so to speak) the effect of $s_n \to 0$ is for $x_n \to \infty$.  Try $s_n = \frac 1n$.  Can you find a sequence $x_n$ s.t. $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_ns_n \ne 0$?

Comment: In this case you just need to show *one* counter example.  $s_n $ converges to zero but $x_n $ can be anything.  If we *don't* want $s_nx_n $ to go to zero you just need $x_n $ to "get bigger" as $s_n$ "gets small".  For  example let $x_n = 1/s_n $.  Then $x_ns_n  =1$ and $x_ns_n\rightarrow 1$.  Or even worse: if $s_n=1/n $ and $x_n =n^2$ then $x_n s_n = n \rightarrow \infty $.

Comment: You are right that $x_n $ must be unbounded, but it must be "more unbounded than s_n is bounded".  For example if $s_n = 1/n^2$ and $x_n = n $, $x_n$ is bounded... but not enough.  $x_ns_n = 1/n \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x_n = n$ and $s_n = \displaystyle\frac{1}{n}$.

Then clearly $\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} s_n = 0$ as required.

However, for every $n$, $x_n s_n = 1$.

Therefore $\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} x_n s_n =1$.

The reason why this counterexample works is because the sequence $x_n$ is *not* bounded. The statement is actually true for $x_n$ bounded.

Comment: @jgon I was just about to ask him about that!

Comment: yes I do thanks, oops

Comment: Why is it that for every $n$, $x_ns_n = 1$ if $s_n=0$? Oh because it gives me $\frac{n}{n}$?

Comment: The ***limit*** of the $s_n$ is 0, but for every $n$, $s_n$ is a non-zero number.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance!  Can you tell me if I have the correct thinking in the tirade I posted along with my question?

Comment: "Is disproving this as simple as taking the product of the limits and showing that it DNE?" That is definitely a necessary condition for a counterexample, but I am not sure if it is a sufficient one; no proofs or counterexamples come immediately to mind, although the harmonic series is always good to try for counterexamples, since its terms converge to 0 but its sum diverges to infinity. You are correct that any counterexample must be unbounded/divergent, I am just unsure if whether every unbounded/divergent sequence provides a counterexample, although my gut says no.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n =1/ s_n$. Limit is $1$.

Comment: Sloppy answers tend to get downvotes.

Comment: @soup I don't give a damn about my bad reputation.